# Error too few arguments in function call

Tags: c++

Hey im getting an error  too few arguments in function call for both my calculateSrabbleScore codes at the brackets, and im unsure why. I've added my calculateScrabbleScore(); to main post.

Comment: Is it too much to ask you for the _declaration_ of `calculateScrabbleScore()`?

Comment: Ok. Now you added the signature: `double calculateScrabbleScore(string Word)`. See the part `(string Word)`? It means the function takes _one_ parameter, of type string. You are calling it with zero parameters. This is causing the compile error "too few arguments in function call" that you mentioned, as weird as it may seem.

Comment: @DanielDaranas  Adding `Dic.GetWord1` inside the brackets fix it?

Comment: _Anything_ which has type `string`. I don't know the types you are using in your application.

Comment: @DanielDaranas When I add `Dic.GetWord1` It then gives an error function call missing argument..

Comment: Please post the updated code. But take into account that calling functions with the appropriate parameters is a very basic operation. People might suspect that you are trolling.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I'm not, just clueless... Updated

Comment: Please post (1) the declaration of `Dic.GetWord1` and (2) your complete new compile error message, including line number. While we're at it, `int score = Dic.GetWord1(i)->calculateScrabbleScore(Dic.GetWord1(i));` is too long a line by my standards, so you might as well split it into a couple of lines, especially if you are having this kind of "obscure" compile errors. Try to do it soon - if more people wake up and see this question, they will close it.

Comment: I'm not going to spoonfeed you every line of code. `calculateScrabbleScore` takes a `string`, so you need to pass a `string` to it - not any other object.

Answer (score 6):

The method `calculateScrabbleScore` is declared to take some arguments and you did not provide any just like the error message suggests. Have a look at the declaration and you should be able to figure this problem out.

EDIT: after you have posted the function definition I can tell that you should pass a string as argument to `calculateScrabbleScore`.